# Do virtual particles appear in a particle accelerator and cause a type of pollution?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, virtual-particles, particle-accelerators

please note (as may be obvious from my question) that I am not trained in physics so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Do [virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) appear in a particle accelerator and get accelerated in opposite directions before tunneling back to each other and annihilating each other?

If so, do they cause a type of 'pollution' in the accelerator?

If not, why not?

Edit for clarification:
My limited understanding of virtual particles is that they come into existence in matter/antimatter pairs and then join together in annihilation. So, if that was true could they appear in a particle accelerator and get separated by the electric fields and accelerated away in opposite directions? Also, if they appeared spontaneously in a particle accelerator could they interfere with the accelerated experimental particles thereby causing a type of pollution (or experimental noise)? Again, sorry if this question is daft.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood the question, but here are some thoughts that did not fit in the comment box.

- When two protons collide in the LHC, there are many processes that occur, which are mediated by virtual particles. These include annihilation processes, but also others, such as scattering and decay. Often, we are most interested in a specific subset of processes, such as those that produce a Higgs boson. From that point of view, the vast majority of processes that actually occur in the LHC form a large and mostly uninteresting *background* that mask the interesting few processes we actually want to find. You could think of this background as a kind of pollution, that makes it hard for an experimentalist to find the "gold nuggets", aka the interesting processes that have never been discovered before.
- Particles that the LHC produce either don't escape the machine, or don't interact strongly with humans or the environment. So, particles produced by the LHC do not cause environmental pollution. (Although, it takes a lot of energy to run the LHC, and there are greenhouse gas emissions produced by machinery that cools the magnets, so the LHC does need to be aware of its impact on the environment; see eg https://home.cern/news/news/cern/environmental-awareness-greenhouse-gas-emissions)
- Virtual particles are not really particles, but a colorful language for describing mathematical terms used to compute the probability for various processes to occur. In particular, virtual particles do not have a trajectory. So, it is not really correct to use words like "acceleration" in association with virtual particles, which are only defined for classical particles that have a trajectory. Additionally, the word "tunneling" has a special meaning in quantum mechanics, and generally does not apply to the kinds of scattering processes in the LHC.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question, Andrew. Just to clarify where I was coming from, my limited understanding of virtual particles is that they come into existence in matter/antimatter pairs and then join together in annihilation. So, if that was true could they appear in a particle accelerator and get separated by the electric fields and accelerated away in opposite directions? Also, if they appeared spontaneously in a particle accelerator could they interfere with the accelerated experimental particles thereby causing a type of pollution? Again, sorry if this question is daft

Comment: I don't think the question is daft, although I think it takes a bit of practice to be able to express what you mean precisely in a complicated subject like particle physics. Virtual particles do not just appear because of annihilation of matter-antimatter pairs. In fact I think it's generally unhelpful for beginners to think too much about virtual particles; the name is very misleading. I think a more accurate picture is that you send in some protons, then there is a fuzzy, quantum cloud, and then some particles come out. We want to learn things about the fuzzy cloud, such as whether...

Comment: ...a Higgs boson was involved, but you shouldn't try to "resolve" what's going on inside the cloud in too much detail. (Expressing precisely what this quantum cloud is requires some math). Re an electric field accelerating the particles/anti-particles: there is not a strong electric field in the LHC tunnel, so this effect should not really happen. Re pollution: I don't really know what you mean by pollution. Processes that aren't the ones we are interested in occur and make it harder to detect interesting things, which is "pollution". Particles in the LHC don't cause environmental pollution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew

Comment: @Andrew if I understand OP correctly, he is not talking about environmental pollution, but rather pollution within the vacuum of the LHC itself. Now, in fact, there is a lot of pollution (or rather, contamination), although its source is simply vacuum leaks and molecules adsorbed to the surfaces of the materials within the vacuum (beam pipes, beam screens, ...). And yes, they are an issue, causing steady beam losses due to the beam particles (protons or heavy ions) interacting with the gas. Sometimes it even causes huge issues, such as when there was frozen nitrogen contamination in 16L2.

Comment: also, there are strong electric fields in the LHC, inside the RF cavities used for acceleration as well as in the transverse feedback (ADT). These locations are however far from the collisions points.